# Unable to debug "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Background: I am working through a flashcard Skill that enables Alexa to ask basic questions about a programming language. The user can choose between Ruby, Python or JS.

The progression goes:

- `LaunchRequest` welcomes the user, then asks for their language preference
- User responds, causing `SetLanguageIntent` to trigger
- A question is then asked of the user

However, I am unable to get past the `SetLanguageIntent` without encountering "There was a problem with the requested skill's response".

Here is the dialogue:
[image]

As one can see from the response, `SetLanguageIntent` is activated properly with the slot `ruby` also matching correctly.

```
"request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.743f750e-96d9-4ef9-aeba-e0aec2e45afb",
        "timestamp": "2018-09-12T13:35:25Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "intent": {
            "name": "SetMyLanguageIntent",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
            "slots": {
                "language": {
                    "name": "language",
                    "value": "ruby",
                    "resolutions": {
                        "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                            {
                                "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.ee34487d-d343-4deb-ab6c-193777c92aa8.languages",
                                "status": {
                                    "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                                },
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": {
                                            "name": "ruby",
                                            "id": "58e53d1324eef6265fdb97b08ed9aadf"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                }
            }
        }
```

However, at this point the error message "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" always appears. There are no errors reported on CloudWatch Logs.

For reference, here is the `SetLanguageIntent` code. As noted in the comment, the test "Okay" should at least have been said. However, it does not get executed.

```
'SetMyLanguageIntent': function() {

    this.response.speak('Okay'); //this should at least have been said

    this.attributes.flashcards.currentLanguage = this.event.request.intent.slots.languages.value;
    var currentLanguage = this.attributes.flashcards.currentLanguage

    this.response
      .speak('Okay, I will ask you some questions about ' +
        currentLanguage + '. Here is your first question. ' + 
        AskQuestion(this.attributes))
      .listen(AskQuestion(this.attributes));

    this.emit(':responseReady');
  },
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: updated with slot names

[image]

Comment: Can you log the response JSON generated and share it

Comment: @CicilThomas thanks for commenting. Unfortunately the JSON output is just "null"

Comment: what does this function do AskQuestion(this.attributes))

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem with your code. This is why you're probably having an issue. You are trying to access an undefined property `this.event.request.intent.slots.languages.value`. The mistake is word **languages**. It should be language.

So the way to acces a slot value should be: 
`this.event.request.intent.slots.language.value`

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought it was a great insight, but when altering from the plural to singular didn't get rid of the problem. I've updated my question with the slots that I am using from the Alexa Console

Comment: Chmm, then you have to try to identify the problem in another way. Is there really nothing in the cloudwatch logs? Also I would recommend to implement "SessionEndedRequest", if you haven't done that and log error, that you get. Another thing. If you can, provide what typo of response do you get when making this request. This might shed some more light what is wrong. But basically, try to log as much info as possible, make sure that functions work as intended and that they access properties in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem for myself by simply adding a `cardRenderer()` to my response. Like this:

```
this.response.speak("my text").cardRenderer("ttitle","some content","image");
```

In the test simulator's device log, I noticed the **card renderer show up, saying the skill responded with a failure**. So I took a shot and it worked. Hopefully this fixes it for you too!